# Android open Accessory for microcontrollers

Tags: android, c, embedded, usb

How to implement the Android open accessory  code in any microcontrollers(8051 core...Such as AT89C51) which has a USB or an external USB driver IC and make the android device communicate with it. Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html), the ADK is designed for Arduino platforms.  However, the Open Accessory protocol is [documented](http://source.android.com/tech/accessories/index.html), so in theory could be implemented on any suitable target.

Be aware however that the protocol requires that the *accessory* behave as a USB host - so the USB controller needs to be host capable, and will need a USB host stack.  On the other hand, being a host, you do not need a [USB-IF](http://www.usb.org/about) assigned vendor ID.

Comment: Thanks Clifford...My USB Controller is Host mode supported and in my board it is already used to communicate through USB to another uc board i want to implement AOA to make it communicate with Android...I have another doubt about the AOA and USB...Does AOA protocol has the same standard of operation as in standard USB protocol, only the API has been changed ? or the entire communication standard itself changed ?...

Comment: It is a software protocol which works on top of standard (or very nearly-standard, that business about the phone changing ID's is odd) USB.

Comment: In android i found some files got created in the /dev folder(when i insert usb device) same as in linux but i could not echo any of the datas through it. can you help me with this why is it so?

Comment: @krishna:  I have no idea, I just found the documentation and pointed to it. That would have been my starting point if it were my problem rather than perhaps posting to StackOverflow. I have no experience of Open Accessory it or even Android.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need USB host driver working on your MC to be able to send and receive data through USB endpoints.
After that you should use EP0 ( standard control EP ) to send necessary command sequence to switch android device into accessory mode. After that you should read device descriptor again and check VID and PID values. They should indicate that your android device now in accessory mode.
After that your device will have one configuration with two BULK EP which you can use to transfer data.
If you don't have usb host controller driver for your MC you can do the same using libusb under Win or Linux platform.